# Is there any reason for the nested filters to be applied on the first case and not in the second one?

Tags: filters, hooks, conditional-tags

// This Works -> Filters are applied

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function(){
    $type = get_current_screen()->post_type;
    
    if(is_admin()){ // "true"
        add_filter('upload_dir', function($uploads){
            $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . "/ordenanzas";
            $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . "/ordenanzas";
            return $uploads;
        });
        add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function($file){       
            $file['name'] = "ORD-" . $file['name'];
            return $file;
        });
    }
});
```

// This Doesn't Works -> Filters aren't applied

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function(){
    $type = get_current_screen()->post_type;
    
    if(is_admin() && $type == 'ordenanzas'){ // when is "true" filters do not work
        add_filter('upload_dir', function($uploads){
            $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . "/ordenanzas";
            $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . "/ordenanzas";
            return $uploads;
        });
        add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function($file){       
            $file['name'] = "ORD-" . $file['name'];
            return $file;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you even sure that upload handling is actually performed on the post type admin screen? Quite often that's handled by an AJAX request in the background so `get_current_screen()` would not even have a post_type.

Comment: The first case does exactly what I need. The problem is in the second case. When I am on a certain page, in this case "ordenanzas", despite evaluating "true", the filters inside are not applied. Just removing the evaluation of post_type works again. (It's not a truthiness problem, also in the second case I tested the values returned by the filters and they are the same as in the first case, they just don't apply.). I think there is some fundamental concept about filters that I don't know.

Comment: Well I explained what the issue is. Your condition is probably evaluating false for the request that’s handling the upload.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand. ```'plupload _default_ params'``` was the filter I needed. Now it's working, thanks Jacob.